# Disable Rally user if deactivated in Clarity

Tags: rally, clarity

I am trying to automate the disabling a ‘Rally user id’ when he/she is deactivated in Clarity.
What is the best way to do this? I have thought of couple of options. Which is good and is there any other better option to do this? Thanks
1) Run a clarity job that will export the list of users who are deactivated in Clarity to a folder on a server. Then another job (scheduled on a windows machine/scheduler) will read this file to disable these users in Rally.
2) Run a clarity job that will read the deactivated user in Clarity and the same job directly calls Rally webservice API to disable this user in Rally.

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to do this via the WSAPI.  The Disabled field on User is writable.  There are rest toolkits for [.NET](https://github.com/RallyTools/RallyRestToolkitFor.NET), [Java](https://github.com/RallyTools/RallyRestToolkitForJava) and [Ruby](https://github.com/RallyTools/RallyRestToolkitForRuby) to help you get started. Not sure what would integrate the easiest with Clarity and/or your language familiarity...